# How to add views in an android application programmatically

Tags: android, view

I've been trying to add a view in my android app, but it keeps throwing an exception.
The view I'm adding is a linearlayout that contains an imageview and a nested linearlayout with 3 textviews. The view I'm adding it to is a LinearLayout with a checkbox, 2 textviews, and a nested relativelayout with a button and an editText.

They are in separate xml files, and I've inflated the view I'm adding. However, when I call addView(), it throws the following exception:

> 06-10 09:24:33.094: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5743): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.projects.twitterOAuth/com.projects.twitterOAuth.twitterOAuth}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 0):

When you inflate your child view, make sure that `parent` parameter (last one) is set to null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already set it to null:

              LinearLayout fpost =       (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fpost, null, true);

I tried it with and without the last parameter, but for some reason when I check it during debugging, when I call fpost.getParent(), it still has a LinearLayout set as its parent.

Comment: I like using `View.inflate()` method. Something like `View.inflate(this, R.layout.fpost,null)`. But in your case, give it last param `false` not to attach to root.